# Mongoose Populate callback undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am running a query in Mongo so that I can only display all subcollections of the schema except for the account ID. However, I get undefined as the result of the callback "list_data". This is how my query is written in my routes:

```
exports.list_data = function(req, res){
  models.Director.find({})
  .populate("full_name").populate("dob").populate("favorite_movies").populate("favorite_camera")
  .exec(function(err, list_data){
    res.render('users', {"dirs": list_data});
  })
};
```

this is my models:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/lvsAPI');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

//set schema
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var directorSchema = new Schema ({
  account_id: Number,
  full_name: String,
  dob: Date,
  favorite_camera: String,
  favorite_movies: String
});

var Director = mongoose.model("Director", directorSchema);

module.exports = {"Director": Director};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple no results.
And **your schema wrong for use populate()**.
Please see [official docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) and just do it right:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
, Schema = mongoose.Schema     

var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

var storySchema = Schema({
  _creator : { type: Number, ref: 'Person' },
  title    : String,
  fans     : [{ type: Number, ref: 'Person' }]
});

var Story  = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

The **ref** option is what tells Mongoose which model to use during population.
Now 'ref' fields will be populated:

```
Story
 .findOne({ title: 'Once upon a timex.' })
 .populate('_creator')
 .exec(function (err, story) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log('The creator is %s', story._creator.name);
    // prints "The creator is Aaron"
 })
```

[Population docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)